# Центрирование изображений в ряд

Tags: html, css

Как отцентровать четыре картинки в ряд?

```css
.wrap-glob {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrap-item {
  width: 200px;
  height: 120px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap-glob">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="wrap-item">
            <img src="http://images.vfl.ru/ii/1467368349/bf2f39e3/13219375.png" alt="">
            <p>text 1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="wrap-item">
            <img src="http://images.vfl.ru/ii/1467368349/bf2f39e3/13219375.png" alt="">
            <p>text 2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="wrap-item">
            <img src="http://images.vfl.ru/ii/1467368349/bf2f39e3/13219375.png" alt="">
            <p>text 3</p>
        </div> 
        <div class="wrap-item">
            <img src="http://images.vfl.ru/ii/1467368349/bf2f39e3/13219375.png" alt="">
            <p>text 4</p>
        </div>
        <div class="wrap-item">
            <img src="http://images.vfl.ru/ii/1467368349/bf2f39e3/13219375.png" alt="">
            <p>text 1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="wrap-item">
            <img src="http://images.vfl.ru/ii/1467368349/bf2f39e3/13219375.png" alt="">
            <p>text 2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="wrap-item">
            <img src="http://images.vfl.ru/ii/1467368349/bf2f39e3/13219375.png" alt="">
            <p>text 3</p>
        </div> 
        <div class="wrap-item">
            <img src="http://images.vfl.ru/ii/1467368349/bf2f39e3/13219375.png" alt="">
            <p>text 4</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Пример на [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/a011nujq/1/)

В итоге должно быть [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно без флексов, [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/slippyk/f4ovh6uh/)`

```css
.wrap-glob {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrap-item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 120px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.wrap-item:nth-child(4n+4) {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.wrap-item:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap-glob">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="wrap-item">
            <img src="http://images.vfl.ru/ii/1467368349/bf2f39e3/13219375.png" alt="">
            <p>text 1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="wrap-item">
            <img src="http://images.vfl.ru/ii/1467368349/bf2f39e3/13219375.png" alt="">
            <p>text 2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="wrap-item">
            <img src="http://images.vfl.ru/ii/1467368349/bf2f39e3/13219375.png" alt="">
            <p>text 3</p>
        </div> 
        <div class="wrap-item">
            <img src="http://images.vfl.ru/ii/1467368349/bf2f39e3/13219375.png" alt="">
            <p>text 4</p>
        </div>
        <div class="wrap-item">
            <img src="http://images.vfl.ru/ii/1467368349/bf2f39e3/13219375.png" alt="">
            <p>text 1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="wrap-item">
            <img src="http://images.vfl.ru/ii/1467368349/bf2f39e3/13219375.png" alt="">
            <p>text 2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="wrap-item">
            <img src="http://images.vfl.ru/ii/1467368349/bf2f39e3/13219375.png" alt="">
            <p>text 3</p>
        </div> 
        <div class="wrap-item">
            <img src="http://images.vfl.ru/ii/1467368349/bf2f39e3/13219375.png" alt="">
            <p>text 4</p>
        </div>
        <div class="wrap-item">
            <img src="http://images.vfl.ru/ii/1467368349/bf2f39e3/13219375.png" alt="">
            <p>text 3</p>
        </div> 
        <div class="wrap-item">
            <img src="http://images.vfl.ru/ii/1467368349/bf2f39e3/13219375.png" alt="">
            <p>text 4</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.wrap-glob {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrap {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.wrap-item {
  width: 200px;
  height: 120px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap-glob">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="wrap-item">
            <img src="http://images.vfl.ru/ii/1467368349/bf2f39e3/13219375.png" alt="">
            <p>text 1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="wrap-item">
            <img src="http://images.vfl.ru/ii/1467368349/bf2f39e3/13219375.png" alt="">
            <p>text 2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="wrap-item">
            <img src="http://images.vfl.ru/ii/1467368349/bf2f39e3/13219375.png" alt="">
            <p>text 3</p>
        </div> 
        <div class="wrap-item">
            <img src="http://images.vfl.ru/ii/1467368349/bf2f39e3/13219375.png" alt="">
            <p>text 4</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Можно, например, вот так сделать.

Comment: а можно без флексов?